# Best Compression algorithm for a sequence of integers

Tags: algorithm, compression

I have a large array with a range of integers that are mostly continuous, eg 1-100, 110-160, etc. All integers are positive.
What would be the best algorithm to compress this?
I tried the deflate algorithm but that gives me only 50% compression.
Note that the algorithm cannot be lossy.

All numbers are unique and progressively increasing.

Also if you can point me to the java implementation of such algorithm that would be great.

Comment: Maybe you would get better answers if you provided a real / a bigger sample data set?

Comment: well here is one to think of the data -
int[] data ;
for (int i =0;i < SIZE; i++)
{
  data[i] = i;
}

However, in some cases the distribution may not be totally continuous, eg we may have values from 1- 100, then from 122 - 230.
However, all values are always unique and always increasing.

Comment: You have already provided nice compression in the way you describe your sequence here

Answer (score 87):

We have written recent research papers that survey the best schemes for this problem. Please see:

Daniel Lemire and Leonid Boytsov, Decoding billions of integers per second through vectorization,Software: Practice & Experience 45 (1), 2015. 
http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2137

Daniel Lemire, Nathan Kurz, Leonid Boytsov, SIMD Compression and the Intersection of Sorted Integers, Software: Practice and Experience (to appear) http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.6399

They include an extensive experimental evaluation.

You can find a complete implementation of all techniques in C++11 online:
https://github.com/lemire/FastPFor and https://github.com/lemire/SIMDCompressionAndIntersection

There are also C libraries: https://github.com/lemire/simdcomp and https://github.com/lemire/MaskedVByte

If you prefer Java, please see https://github.com/lemire/JavaFastPFOR

Comment: 4.4 bits per integer is impressive

Comment: I was going to ask questions but then i see "No software is able to reliably compress an array of random numbers." and that rules out why i would want it.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic One cannot reliably compress a stream of random bits, no matter how you try.

Comment: To elaborate on @DanielLemire's comment: every lossless compression can produce a stream that can be decoded to the original, but _no lossless method_ that encodes any (sub)string of length _l_ to something shorter can avoid to produce something longer for at least one string of length _l_.

Comment: I'd already tested the example from source code in github and it's absolutely amazing. Excellent Job!!

Comment: `JavaFastPFOR` is indeed brilliant

Comment: Do you have any version for python?

Comment: @FavorMylikes I, personally, have not written a Python integer compression library, no.

Comment: @DanielLemire - Amazing job! Can this be used to compressed unsigned int (IP Addresses)?

Comment: You can definitively compressed unsigned integers.

Answer (score 41):

First, preprocess your list of values by taking the difference between each value and the previous one (for the first value, assume the previous one was zero). This should in your case give mostly a sequence of ones, which can be compressed much more easily by most compression algorithms.

This is how the PNG format does to improve its compression (it does one of several difference methods followed by the same compression algorithm used by gzip).

Comment: To add to @CesarB answer, one can then compress sequence of repeated numbers e.g. 1,1,1,1 to something 1X4 or 114. In later, first few digit(s) says length of actual digit followed by number of repetitions. This form is useful as most languages are faster with numbers then strings.  Then you compress using deflat, gzip, lz4 etc

Comment: Could an implementation of this work for a series of integers that _wasn't_ entirely increasing?

Answer (score 19):

While you could design a custom algorithm specific to your stream of data, it's probably easier to use an off the shelf encoding algorithm.  I ran a few [tests of compression algorithms available in Java](http://www.theeggeadventure.com/wikimedia/index.php/Java_Data_Compression) and found the following compression rates for a sequence of one million consecutive integers:

```
None        1.0
Deflate     0.50
Filtered    0.34
BZip2       0.11
Lzma        0.06
```

Answer (score 18):

Well, i'm voting for smarter way. All you have to store is [int:startnumber][int/byte/whatever:number of iterations] in this case, you'll turn your example array into 4xInt value. After it you can compress as you want :)

Comment: .. and *then* use deflate for another 50%

Comment: ... and store not the startnumber, but the difference after the last integer instead.

Answer (score 14):

What size are the numbers? In addition to the other answers, you could consider base-128 variant-length encoding, which lets you store smaller numbers in single bytes while still allowing larger numbers. The MSB means "there is another byte" - this is [described](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/encoding.html#varints) here.

Combine this with the other techniques so you are storing "skip size", "take size", "skip size", "take size" - but noting that neither "skip" nor "take" will ever be zero, so we'll subtract one from each (which lets you save an extra byte for a handful of values)

So:

```
1-100, 110-160
```

is "skip 1" (assume start at zero as it makes things easier), "take 100", "skip 9", "take 51"; subtract 1 from each, giving (as decimals)

```
0,99,8,50
```

which encodes as (hex):

```
00 63 08 32
```

If we wanted to skip/take a larger number - 300, for example; we subtract 1 giving 299 - but that goes over 7 bits; starting with the little end, we encode blocks of 7 bits and an MSB to indicate continuation:

```
299 = 100101100 = (in blocks of 7): 0000010 0101100
```

so starting with the little end:

```
1 0101100 (leading one since continuation)
0 0000010 (leading zero as no more)
```

giving:

```
AC 02
```

So we can encode large numbers easily, but small numbers (which sound typical for skip/take) take less space.

You could **try** running this through "deflate", but it might not help much more...

---

If you don't want to deal with all that messy encoding cruff yourself... if you can create the integer-array of the values (0,99,8,60) - you could use [protocol buffers with a packed repeated uint32/uint64](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/proto.html) - and it'll do all the work for you ;-p

I don't "do" Java, but here's a full C# implementation (borrowing some of the encoding bits from my [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) project):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var data = new List<int>();
        data.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 100));
        data.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(110, 51));
        int[] arr = data.ToArray(), arr2;

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Encode(ms, arr);
            ShowRaw(ms.GetBuffer(), (int)ms.Length);
            ms.Position = 0; // rewind to read it...
            arr2 = Decode(ms);
        }
    }
    static void ShowRaw(byte[] buffer, int len)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(buffer[i].ToString("X2"));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    static int[] Decode(Stream stream)
    {
        var list = new List<int>();
        uint skip, take;
        int last = 0;
        while (TryDecodeUInt32(stream, out skip)
            && TryDecodeUInt32(stream, out take))
        {
            last += (int)skip+1;
            for(uint i = 0 ; i <= take ; i++) {
                list.Add(last++);
            }
        }
        return list.ToArray();
    }
    static int Encode(Stream stream, int[] data)
    {
        if (data.Length == 0) return 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
        int last = -1, len = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; )
        {
            int gap = data[i] - 2 - last, size = 0;
            while (++i < data.Length && data[i] == data[i - 1] + 1) size++;
            last = data[i - 1];
            len += EncodeUInt32((uint)gap, buffer, stream)
                + EncodeUInt32((uint)size, buffer, stream);
        }
        return len;
    }
    public static int EncodeUInt32(uint value, byte[] buffer, Stream stream)
    {
        int count = 0, index = 0;
        do
        {
            buffer[index++] = (byte)((value & 0x7F) | 0x80);
            value >>= 7;
            count++;
        } while (value != 0);
        buffer[index - 1] &= 0x7F;
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
        return count;
    }
    public static bool TryDecodeUInt32(Stream source, out uint value)
    {
        int b = source.ReadByte();
        if (b < 0)
        {
            value = 0;
            return false;
        }

        if ((b & 0x80) == 0)
        {
            // single-byte
            value = (uint)b;
            return true;
        }

        int shift = 7;

        value = (uint)(b & 0x7F);
        bool keepGoing;
        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            b = source.ReadByte();
            if (b < 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
            i++;
            keepGoing = (b & 0x80) != 0;
            value |= ((uint)(b & 0x7F)) << shift;
            shift += 7;
        } while (keepGoing && i < 4);
        if (keepGoing && i == 4)
        {
            throw new OverflowException();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @marc "mostly continuous" could be taken to mean 51% continuous in which case, bitmaps are good... :p

Answer (score 5):

[TurboPFor: Fastest Integer Compression](https://github.com/powturbo/TurboPFor)

- for C/C++ including Java Critical Natives/JNI Interface
- SIMD accelerated integer compression
- Scalar + Integrated (SIMD) differential/Zigzag encoding/decoding for sorted/unsorted integer lists
- Full range 8/16/32/64 bits interger lists
- Direct access
- Benchmark app

Comment: This, is the BEST INTEGER COMPRESSION.

Answer (score 3):

compress the string "1-100, 110-160" or store the string in some binary representation and parse it to restore the array

Answer (score 3):

I'd combine the answers given by CesarB and Fernando Miguélez.

First, store the differences between each value and the previous one.  As CesarB pointed out, this will give you a sequence of mostly ones.

Then, use a Run Length Encoding compression algorithm on this sequence.  It will compress very nicely due to the large number of repeated values.

Comment: ...and then apply yet another compression layer on top, for even greater gains. (If you have a binary representation "100:1;1:10;50:1" after the previous steps, another compression method could do something about the leftover redundancy.)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other solutions:

You could find "dense" areas and use a bitmap to store them.

So for example:

If you have 1000 numbers in 400 ranges between 1000-3000, you could use a single bit to denote the existence  of a number and two ints to denote the range. Total storage for this range is 2000 bits + 2 ints, so you can store that info in 254bytes, which is pretty awesome since even short integers will take up two bytes each, so for this example you get 7X savings.

The denser the areas the better this algorithm will do, but at some point just storing start and finish will be cheaper.

Comment: If they are "mostly continuous", then start/end (or similar) will probably be the optimum from the outset; bitmap would be good for blocks of more random data

Comment: I agree, only way to write an optimal algorithm here would be to have some sample data.

Comment: Agree 100% re needing sample data... but since we've arrived 6 months late, I'm not holding my breath ;-p

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old message thread, but I am including my personal PHP test of the SKIP/TAKE idea I found here. I'm calling mine STEP(+)/SPAN(-). Perhaps someone might find it helpful.

NOTE: I implemented the ability to allow duplicate integers as well as negative integers even though the original question involved positive, non-duplicated integers. Feel free to tweak it if you want to try and shave a byte or two.

CODE:

```php
  // $integers_array can contain any integers; no floating point, please. Duplicates okay.
  $integers_array = [118, 68, -9, 82, 67, -36, 15, 27, 26, 138, 45, 121, 72, 63, 73, -35,
                    68, 46, 37, -28, -12, 42, 101, 21, 35, 100, 44, 13, 125, 142, 36, 88,
                    113, -40, 40, -25, 116, -21, 123, -10, 43, 130, 7, 39, 69, 102, 24,
                    75, 64, 127, 109, 38, 41, -23, 21, -21, 101, 138, 51, 4, 93, -29, -13];

  // Order from least to greatest... This routine does NOT save original order of integers.
  sort($integers_array, SORT_NUMERIC); 

  // Start with the least value... NOTE: This removes the first value from the array.
  $start = $current = array_shift($integers_array);    

  // This caps the end of the array, so we can easily get the last step or span value.
  array_push($integers_array, $start - 1);

  // Create the compressed array...
  $compressed_array = [$start];
  foreach ($integers_array as $next_value) {
    // Range of $current to $next_value is our "skip" range. I call it a "step" instead.
    $step = $next_value - $current;
    if ($step == 1) {
        // Took a single step, wait to find the end of a series of seqential numbers.
        $current = $next_value;
    } else {
        // Range of $start to $current is our "take" range. I call it a "span" instead.
        $span = $current - $start;
        // If $span is positive, use "negative" to identify these as sequential numbers. 
        if ($span > 0) array_push($compressed_array, -$span);
        // If $step is positive, move forward. If $step is zero, the number is duplicate.
        if ($step >= 0) array_push($compressed_array, $step);
        // In any case, we are resetting our start of potentialy sequential numbers.
        $start = $current = $next_value;
    }
  }

  // OPTIONAL: The following code attempts to compress things further in a variety of ways.

  // A quick check to see what pack size we can use.
  $largest_integer = max(max($compressed_array),-min($compressed_array));
  if ($largest_integer < pow(2,7)) $pack_size = 'c';
  elseif ($largest_integer < pow(2,15)) $pack_size = 's';
  elseif ($largest_integer < pow(2,31)) $pack_size = 'l';
  elseif ($largest_integer < pow(2,63)) $pack_size = 'q';
  else die('Too freaking large, try something else!');

  // NOTE: I did not implement the MSB feature mentioned by Marc Gravell.
  // I'm just pre-pending the $pack_size as the first byte, so I know how to unpack it.
  $packed_string = $pack_size;

  // Save compressed array to compressed string and binary packed string.
  $compressed_string = '';
  foreach ($compressed_array as $value) {
      $compressed_string .= ($value < 0) ? $value : '+'.$value;
      $packed_string .= pack($pack_size, $value);
  }

  // We can possibly compress it more with gzip if there are lots of similar values.      
  $gz_string = gzcompress($packed_string);

  // These were all just size tests I left in for you.
  $base64_string = base64_encode($packed_string);
  $gz64_string = base64_encode($gz_string);
  $compressed_string = trim($compressed_string,'+');  // Don't need leading '+'.
  echo "<hr>\nOriginal Array has "
    .count($integers_array)
    .' elements: {not showing, since I modified the original array directly}';
  echo "<br>\nCompressed Array has "
    .count($compressed_array).' elements: '
    .implode(', ',$compressed_array);
  echo "<br>\nCompressed String has "
    .strlen($compressed_string).' characters: '
    .$compressed_string;
  echo "<br>\nPacked String has "
    .strlen($packed_string).' (some probably not printable) characters: '
    .$packed_string;
  echo "<br>\nBase64 String has "
    .strlen($base64_string).' (all printable) characters: '
    .$base64_string;
  echo "<br>\nGZipped String has "
    .strlen($gz_string).' (some probably not printable) characters: '
    .$gz_string;
  echo "<br>\nBase64 of GZipped String has "
    .strlen($gz64_string).' (all printable) characters: '
    .$gz64_string;

  // NOTICE: The following code reverses the process, starting form the $compressed_array.

  // The first value is always the starting value.
  $current_value = array_shift($compressed_array);
  $uncompressed_array = [$current_value];
  foreach ($compressed_array as $val) {
    if ($val < -1) {
      // For ranges that span more than two values, we have to fill in the values.
      $range = range($current_value + 1, $current_value - $val - 1);
      $uncompressed_array = array_merge($uncompressed_array, $range);
    }
    // Add the step value to the $current_value
    $current_value += abs($val); 
    // Add the newly-determined $current_value to our list. If $val==0, it is a repeat!
    array_push($uncompressed_array, $current_value);      
  }

  // Display the uncompressed array.
  echo "<hr>Reconstituted Array has "
    .count($uncompressed_array).' elements: '
    .implode(', ',$uncompressed_array).
    '<hr>';
```

OUTPUT:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Original Array has 63 elements: {not showing, since I modified the original array directly}
Compressed Array has 53 elements: -40, 4, -1, 6, -1, 3, 2, 2, 0, 8, -1, 2, -1, 13, 3, 6, 2, 6, 0, 3, 2, -1, 8, -11, 5, 12, -1, 3, -1, 0, -1, 3, -1, 2, 7, 6, 5, 7, -1, 0, -1, 7, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 8, 0, 4
Compressed String has 110 characters: -40+4-1+6-1+3+2+2+0+8-1+2-1+13+3+6+2+6+0+3+2-1+8-11+5+12-1+3-1+0-1+3-1+2+7+6+5+7-1+0-1+7+4+3+2+3+2+2+2+3+8+0+4
Packed String has 54 (some probably not printable) characters: cØÿÿÿÿ ÿõ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ
Base64 String has 72 (all printable) characters: Y9gE/wb/AwICAAj/Av8NAwYCBgADAv8I9QUM/wP/AP8D/wIHBgUH/wD/BwQDAgMCAgIDCAAE
GZipped String has 53 (some probably not printable) characters: xœ Ê» ÑÈÎ¯€)YšE¨MŠ“^qçºR¬m&Òõ‹%Ê&TFÊ‰ùÀ6ÿÁÁ Æ
Base64 of GZipped String has 72 (all printable) characters: eJwNyrsNACAMA9HIzq+AKVmaRahNipNecee6UgSsBW0m0gj1iyXKJlRGjcqJ+cA2/8HBDcY=
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Reconstituted Array has 63 elements: -40, -36, -35, -29, -28, -25, -23, -21, -21, -13, -12, -10, -9, 4, 7, 13, 15, 21, 21, 24, 26, 27, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 51, 63, 64, 67, 68, 68, 69, 72, 73, 75, 82, 88, 93, 100, 101, 101, 102, 109, 113, 116, 118, 121, 123, 125, 127, 130, 138, 138, 142
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Side-notes...

  If you don't want duplicates, change "if ($step >= 0)" to "if ($step > 0)" in the compression loop. Also add "if ($val)" to the "array_push($uncompressed_array, $current_value)" in the decompression part, if client's could potentially manipulate the data.

  I am using this to send a "snapshot" of local client DB ID's through a cookie to the server to compare with the server's DB, so that the server can send Inserts, Updates, or Deletes for syncing in initial page load (instead of requiring AJAX)... duplicate ID's are not welcome in this case, neither are negatives.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest taking a look at [Huffman Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding), a special case of [Arithmetic Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding).  In both cases you analyse your starting sequence to determine the relative frequencies of different values.  More-frequently-occurring values are encoded with fewer bits than the less-frequently-occurring ones.

Comment: As i mentioned, all values in the array are unique. no repetitions.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have been explicit: you would of course have to pre-process your set in the same way as for the RLE suggestions.

Comment: Huffman coding on the deltas should be quite efficient, if the deltas are mostly +1.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get my compression to be much better than about .11 for this. I generated my test data via python interpreter and it's a newline delimited list of integers from 1-100, and 110-160. I use the actual program as a compressed representation of the data. My compressed file is as follows:

```
main=mapM_ print [x|x<-[1..160],x`notElem`[101..109]]
```

It's just a Haskell script that generates the the file you can run via:

```
$ runhaskell generator.hs >> data
```

The size of the g.hs file is 54 bytes, and the python generated data is 496 bytes. This gives 0.10887096774193548 as the compression ratio. I think with more time one could shrink the program, or you could compress the compressed file (i.e. the haskell file).

One other approach might be to save 4 bytes of data. The min and max of each sequence, then give those to a generating function. Albeit, the loading of files will add more characters to the decompresser adding more complexity and more bytes to the decompresser. Again, I represented this very specific sequence via a program and it doesn't generalize, it's a compression that's specific to the data. Furthermore, adding generality makes the decompresser larger.

Another concern is that one must have the Haskell interpreter to run this. When I compiled the program it made it much larger. I don't really know why. There is the same problem with python, so maybe the best approach is to give the ranges, so that a some program could decompress the file.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea you should probably use is, for each range of consecutive integers (I will call these ranges), to store the starting number and the size of the range. For example, if you have a list of 1000 integers, but there are only 10 separate ranges, you can store a mere 20 integers (1 start number and 1 size for each range) to represent this data which would be a compression rate of 98%. Fortunately, there are some more optimizations you can make which will help with cases where the number of ranges is larger.

1. **Store the offset** of the starting number relative to the previous starting number, rather than the starting number itself. The advantage here is that the numbers you store will generally require less bits (this may come in handy in later optimization suggestions). Additionally, if you only stored the starting numbers, these numbers would all be unique, while storing the offset gives a chance that the numbers are close or even repeat which may allow for even further compression with another method being applied after.
2. Use the **minimum number of bits possible** for both types of integers. You can iterate over the numbers to obtain the largest offset of a starting integer as well as the size of the largest range. You can then use a datatype that most efficiently stores these integers and simply specify the datatype or number of bits at the start of the compressed data. For example, if the largest offset of a starting integer is only 12,000, and the largest range is 9,000 long, then you can use a 2 byte unsigned integer for all of these. You could then cram the pair 2,2 at the start of the compressed data to show that 2 bytes is used for both integers. Of course you can fit this information into a single byte using a little bit of bit manipulation. If you are comfortable with doing a lot of heavy bit manipulation you could store each number as the minimum possible amount of bits rather than conforming to 1, 2, 4, or 8 byte representations.

With those two optimizations lets look at a couple of examples (each is 4,000 bytes):

1. 1,000 integers, biggest offset is 500, 10 ranges
2. 1,000 integers, biggest offset is 100, 50 ranges
3. 1,000 integers, biggest offset is 50, 100 ranges

**WITHOUT OPTIMIZATIONS**

1. 20 integers, 4 bytes each = 80 bytes. COMPRESSION = **98%**
2. 100 integers, 4 bytes each = 400 bytes. COMPRESSION = **90%**
3. 200 integers, 4 bytes each = 800 bytes. COMPRESSION = **80%**

**WITH OPTIMIZATIONS**

1. 1 byte header + 20 numbers, 1 byte each = 21 bytes. COMPRESSION = **99.475%**
2. 1 byte header + 100 numbers, 1 byte each = 101 bytes. COMPRESSION = **97.475%**
3. 1 byte header + 200 numbers, 1 byte each = 201 bytes. COMPRESSION = **94.975%**

Comment: For info, variant-length encoding would allow you to have occasional large values without having to make everything wide.

Answer (score 1):

Your case is very similar to compression of indices in search engines. The popular compression algorithm used is the PForDelta algorithm and Simple16 algorithm. You can use the kamikaze library for your compression needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have series of repeated values RLE is the easiest to implement and could give you a good result. Nontheless other more advanced algorithms that take into account the entrophy such as LZW, which is now patent-free, can usually achive a much better compression.

You can take a look at these and other lossless algorithms [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_data_compression).