# Compression algorithms for a sequence of integers

Tags: algorithm, compression

Are there any good compression algorithms for a large sequence of integers (A/D converter data). There is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283299/best-compression-algorithm-for-a-sequence-of-integers)

But the data is different in my case. It can be negarive or positive and changing like wave data.

EDIT1:sample data added

[Please refer to this file](http://www.filedropper.com/file_391) for a data sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a Delta Encode and then you want to apply a RLE or a Golomb Code. The Golomb Code can be as good as a Huffman Code.

Comment: what if I use Huffman code without Delta encode? THere will be int values(4 bytes each) and I will treat that data as a sequence of bytes. And each byte can take 256 values. Do you think this will work well?

Comment: So at the end you have a 256 alphabet? Huffman would do well (I've some experience with this) but I would try a Golomb Code.

Comment: The golomb code made from 65536 bytes 50280 bytes. Not good... I need at least 30% from original size.

Comment: It seems to me that FLAC also uses Golomb-Code. Maybe can copy that linear prediction?

Comment: I will think about that. Huffman code failed. may be because the data is wave like and DELTA ENcode gives in a simple case (a[n] -= a[n-1]) not so good advantage. 65kb -> 61kb only. with Delta Encode : 65 -> 55kb. For comparison, Winrar gives 48 kb. But I need at least 30%, 65->20kb. any ideas?

Comment: 30% is doable with a huffman code or an arithmetic coder and english text. Maybe you can try a range coder? But if Winrar isn't that good. You want to ask in the newsgroup comp.compression. Maybe you have more luck there?

Comment: Huffman coding depends on probabilities of data. SO sometimes it works good, sometimes bad, for example if I encode a sequence of numbers from 0 to 255, no compression will be made. (or even may be it will grow in size). I will try range coder if it is possible to use it and may be also arithmetic coder

Comment: AFAIK I would try to copy that lineaer prediction from flac. I don't think your problem is coding but the preprocessing. And also the range coder is essentially the same like arithmetic coder but the latter is patented. What about Delta Encode and Golomb Code? Do you know that the Golomb Code has a tuneable parameter?

Comment: I tried Golomb Code but it is even worse. Please refer to this link to see the data sample: http://www.filedropper.com/file_391 I hope you can tell me more after seeing the data sample.

Comment: Didn't you say: The golomb code made from 65536 bytes 50280 bytes? This is as good as Winrar. I've read the file. I don't know what to do. Go ask comp.compression or encode.ru.

Comment: ok, thank you very much. I will try to ask there. Yes it did so, I just forgot. But test data changed now. More realistic they are now.

Comment: By the way, the encode.ru requires the registration which is disabled now. The comp.compression is it a google group?

Comment: sorry mate, comp.compression isn't a google group. Maybe you want to wait a little for encode.ru? I can ask for you in encode.ru but I don't I've that much time! And also the guys there a very special. Ask them about recursive compression!

Comment: The link to your sample data on filedropper.com doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Generally if you have some knowledge about the signal, use it to predict next value basing on previous ones. Then - compress difference between predicted and real value.

If prediction is good, differences will be small and their compressing will be good.

Anything more specific is unlikely possible without seeing the data and knowing about its physical nature.

**update:**

If the prediction is really well and uses all knowledge about dependencies, the differences are likely to be independent and something like arithmetic encoding would work for them.

Comment: I just want to choose the right one, but need some info about the methods existing. Loseless compression required

Answer (score 2):

Nearly any standard compression algorithm for byte strings can be applied; after all, any file of data can be interpreted as a sequence of signed integers. Is there something special about your particular integers that you think will make them amenable to some more-specific algorithm? You mention wave data; maybe take a look at [FLAC](http://flac.sourceforge.net/) which is designed for audio data; if your data has similar characteristics those techniques may be valuable.

Answer (score 1):

You could diff the data then apply RLE on suitable subregions (i.e. between inflection points).