# Compression of a 2D point set - ideas?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, compression

I have a set of 2D points stored in an array. **I need to compress it as much as I can.** Preferably fast, but not a deal breaker, compression rate is the goal. The rules are:

- a point = a 32-bit structure, stored as (x,y), 2 bytes for each coordinate
- a coordinate = a "float" with 8 bits integer part, 8 bits fractional part

Special properties:

- **I may change the order of the points as I see fit**
- I'm given the points in the order of the integer parts of their x and y, maybe I can exploit that, but the fractional parts are pretty much random from what I saw
- the array I receive is contiguous (from a memory standpoint)

What I've researched so far:

- consider them plain integers (32 bit), sort them (the order is mine to choose), then compress it as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283299/best-compression-algorithm-for-a-sequence-of-integers).
- consider my array as a plain char string, then apply [a Burrows-Wheeler transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform) (BWT) with [run-length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding), or [Huffman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)
- treat my array as plain binary data, then apply an [LZW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch)

I only managed to implement Huffman and BWT, but neither of them gives me a good compression ratio (or use the main property of my data set). I'm going to try the first option today.

**I'm sure there are better ideas. Do you have any?** Did you come across anything similar and implemented something really good?

Dataset example, in hex:

```
00 0A 00 77 00 55 00 80 00 2B 00 B9 00 7A 00 5B 
00 F6 00 76 00 B4 00 25 00 47 00 D3 00 F6 00 7D
...
01 05 00 A9 01 B8 00 10 01 4F 00 6A 01 E6 00 DF
01 1F 00 F0 01 BE 00 C3 01 6C 00 87 01 CE 00 44
...
...
15 06 03 F4 15 1E 03 29 15 35 03 10 15 B9 03 22
15 67 03 73 15 EF 03 5C 15 29 03 B8 15 4C 03 2F
...
```

where e.g. the particle `15 67 03 73` (last row) means particle at x = 15 and 67/256, y = 3 and 73/256. As you see, the data is somewhat ordered but the fractional parts are in a total disarray.

Comment: That "float" is actually a "fixed". Anyway what does your data set look like?

Comment: Yes, it's some kind of fixed decimal. The fractional parts look random to me, but the integer parts are ordered (first by x, then by y). I added an example to the question.

Comment: I would do integer and fractional parts separately. 1. you could try RLE  (run length encoding) and may be huffman after  for Integer parts.  2. the fractional part is tricky I would try only Hufman on it.

Comment: Unless you know something about the distribution, the best possible algorithm is to rank and unrank the multisets.

Comment: Is lossy compression an option?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have to be able to rebuild the dataset, even though the order of the points may be changed. Did you have an idea? Maybe I can adapt it...

Comment: if order can change then handle points as 32 bit numbers sort asc or desc and encode by delta coding (delta will be in most cases less bit wide ...) and the delta coding may be even better compressible after

Comment: How many points do you expect, are there any limits? And, are the points completely random or there would be clusters or hot-areas?

Comment: I don't know anything (yet) about the distribution, I'm going to assume a purely random one. About the number of points, I'm not supposed to assume any limit. Did you have something in mind?

Comment: If they are completely random, the only compression possible would be that based on the fact that you don't need to keep the order.

Comment: That's the point, yes...

Comment: You may try interleave x and y bits, sort, delta-code. (I'd probably try xyyxxyyxxyyxxyyxxyyxxyyxxyyxxyyx.)

Answer (score 4):

First option from OP is more appropriate. But it may be improved further.

1. Reinterpret coordinates as 16-bit integers.
2. Transform point positions into distances along Hilbert curve (or any other Space-filling curve).
3. Sort distances, then apply delta-encoding (compute differences of adjacent distances).
4. Depending on compression/speed preferences, (a) use something like Elias or Golomb codes (fastest), (b) use Huffman encoding, or (c) use something like arithmetic encoding (best compression rate).

If there is some pattern in points' distribution, you could try more advanced compressors for step #4: LZ*, BWT, or PPM.

---

Here are results of experimental comparison for methods used in step 4. Worst-case scenario is assumed: points are randomly uniformly distributed in range 00.00 .. FF.FF (so that the only compression possibility is to lose information about their ordering). All results are computed for 250000 points:

```
method        compressed size
------        ---------------
Uncompressed: 1000000
Elias4:        522989
Elias3:        495371
Elias2:        505376
Golomb12:      479802
Golomb13:      472238
Golomb14:      479431
Golomb15:      501422
FSE1:          455367
FSE2:          454120
FSE3:          453862
```

I didn't try Huffman encoding. [FSE](https://github.com/Cyan4973/FiniteStateEntropy) is a method similar to arithmetic coding. Numbers after method name show configuration parameters: for Elias coding - how many bits are used to encode each number's bitlength, for Golomb coding - how many least significant bits are left uncompressed, for FSE - how many most significant bits are compressed (along with bitlength).

All the results were produced by this source: http://ideone.com/ulmPzO

Comment: Can you elaborate on the Hilbert curve?

Comment: Hilbert curve maps your points from 2D space to 1D while preserving locality (which means distance deltas after step 3 tend to be small, therefore may be compressed better). IMHO Hilbert curve preserves locality slightly better than other space-filling curves, though it requires slightly more complicated implementation compared to other curves (idea proposed by salva is identical to Z-curve, which has simplest implementation).

Comment: Before mapping coordinates to Hilbert curve you may start with mapping area occupied by points (except possibly some outliers) to square area occupied by Hilbert curve. Which means possibly upscaling both coordinates so that height/width are extended to next-power-of-two. Algorithm for mapping coordinates to distance and back are well known, you could find them for example in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve).

Comment: Hilbert curve as well as Z-curve or other space-filling curves will not help if your points are randomly uniformly distributed. In this case I would prefer to map the points to 1D in simpler way: `d=x+y*w` where `w` is width of the points' area.

Answer (score 1):

Interleave the bits representing the X and Y coordinates of every point, sort and compress.

For instance, if you have the point (X, Y) represented by the two 16 bit numbers

(X<sub>15</sub>X<sub>14</sub>X<sub>13</sub>X<sub>12</sub>X<sub>11</sub>X<sub>10</sub>X<sub>9</sub>X<sub>8</sub>X<sub>7</sub>X<sub>6</sub>X<sub>5</sub>X<sub>4</sub>X<sub>3</sub>X<sub>2</sub>X<sub>1</sub>X<sub>0</sub>, Y<sub>15</sub>Y<sub>14</sub>Y<sub>13</sub>Y<sub>12</sub>Y<sub>11</sub>Y<sub>10</sub>Y<sub>9</sub>Y<sub>8</sub>Y<sub>7</sub>Y<sub>6</sub>Y<sub>5</sub>Y<sub>4</sub>Y<sub>3</sub>Y<sub>2</sub>Y<sub>1</sub>Y<sub>0</sub>)

Convert it into the following 32 bit number:

X<sub>15</sub>Y<sub>15</sub>X<sub>14</sub>Y<sub>14</sub>X<sub>13</sub>Y<sub>13</sub>X<sub>12</sub>Y<sub>12</sub>X<sub>11</sub>Y<sub>11</sub>X<sub>10</sub>Y<sub>10</sub>X<sub>9</sub>Y<sub>9</sub>X<sub>8</sub>Y<sub>8</sub>X<sub>7</sub>Y<sub>7</sub>X<sub>6</sub>Y<sub>6</sub>X<sub>5</sub>Y<sub>5</sub>X<sub>4</sub>Y<sub>4</sub>X<sub>3</sub>Y<sub>3</sub>X<sub>2</sub>Y<sub>2</sub>X<sub>1</sub>Y<sub>1</sub>X<sub>0</sub>Y<sub>0</sub>

That would take advantage of any clustering that may appear in the data, as near physically near points will appear in near positions on the sorted list and their representations share their head bits.

**Update**: The point is to have near points sort in near positions. If you mix X and Y bits, you get that, resulting on long sequences of 32bit integers which identical values in its head bits. If you then do deltas, you will have smaller values that if you just sort on X and then on Y (or vice versa).

The thing is that then, you can consider it as a k-d tree, every bit partitions the space (left/right or up/down). For the first levels, you can compress then just saying how many elements there are at one side until you get to the poles with just a few elements that can be represented by stating the remaining few bits explicitly. For the best compression you will have to use arithmetic coding.

Comment: So you say rewrite the points with interleaved bits, sort and compress with run length encoding? How is it better than without interleaved bits?