# Java compress lots of long numbers

Tags: java, performance, compression

I need to compress lots of long numbers. Those long numbers are like database ids. After compression, it will be sent as part of the request. Other than `java.util.zip`, is there any better alternative to achieve higher compression rate?

Thanks

Comment: Your question makes no sense. First, why do you want to compress them? What are they? Why do you think you need to compress at all?

Comment: It highly depends on the nature of these number. For example, if they are randomly distributed throughout the whole 64-bit range, you won't be able to compress them at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate?  int vs. long, but process should be the same.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283299/best-compression-algorithm-for-a-sequence-of-integers

Comment: You need to provide much more information on the nature of your numbers. Their range, required accuracy, correlations from number to number.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change byte length of a any number by changing its radix. As computers use bytes for data (radix 256) and humans use base 10 cleartext numbers are not space efficient as they can be use only 10 values out of 256 possible.

Simple java program to demonstrate:

```
System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);
String sa = Long.toString(Long.MAX_VALUE, Character.MAX_RADIX);
System.out.println(sa);
```

Outputs:

```
9223372036854775807              # 20 bytes
1y2p0ij32e8e7                    # 14 bytes
```

Which is a 6 byte reduction (30% compression** in bytes). As Character.MAX_RADIX equals 36 you can achieve even greater compression by writing custom toString method.

Of course this works only for textual representation of numbers. Long.MAX_VALUE number used in this example is only 8 bytes long in its binary form. So even this 30% reduction in size is actually 75% increase when compared to a binary form of the number.

** This method is not really a compression. This is only exploit of storage inefficiency introduced by writing numbers in human readable form. Actual compression like zip will always beat this method, although it will make numbers unreadable by humans. To put it bluntly: you can read aloud numbers in base 10, 16, 36 or even 256. You can't read compressed numbers.

Answer (score -1):

You can compress long numbers using Run Length Encoding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding