# linux tools for highest compression of sorted integers

Tags: encoding, compression, gzip, huffman-code

I am looking for a tried-and-true Linux tools specifically designed for:

1. simple run length encoding
2. compression of sorted integers.

---

**1.** I have a sorted list of repeated words, one per line, 1.5 Gb text file (617 million lines). There are ~200 unique words, ranging from 1 to < 20 characters in length.

I can "manually compress" using `uniq -c` to get a 3.4 Kb file that is 1.2 Kb when gzipped.  I could then do a "manually decompression" with a simple awk function. A tested, optimized, maintained, dedicated tool is much preferable and less error-prone and more time effective to writing my own code, of course.

`gzip --best` gives a 1.5Mb file, which is a woefully poor compression ratio for this particular problem.

`bzip2 --best` gives a 62 Kb compressed file, which is good, but obviously suboptimal compression ratio.  And it takes far longer than simply `uniq -c`.

A simple tool with a straightforward implementation of Run Length Encoding seems optimal, but I cannot find anything standard and reliable.

---

**2.**  I have a sorted list of positive integers, one per line. Each integer is approximately in the range of 1 Million to 300 million. There is no algorithmic pattern or formula, they are random.  But the difference between consecutive integers is tightly distributed around 0 to 30, though with a tail.

Huffman Coding of the difference of consecutive integers (or the difference of the difference) should give very high compression ratio.  but I cannot find a simple, dedicated tool for sorted integers.

[Another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14843041/1023645) gives links to C libraries for these problems, but I am looking for a maintained, standalone Linux binary.

---

These are simple problems, but I don't have time to write my own code, debug it, test it, optimize it, etc.  This is a tiny piece of a larger project.  I am surprised there are not dedicated Linux utility tools for these problems.

Comment: For the second one, why not to write a simple script to map the original list to their consecutive differences?

Comment: i can certainly though that.  But is there a tool specifically designed for compression of difference-of-sorted-integers that could use it? For example, i don't know of a tool that explicitly implements huffman coding.

Comment: I don't know, but if I were in your case I would do what did you said. If the difference between two numbers is in the range of 0-30, compressing that dataset (which requires 5 bits or less) would give good results.

Comment: Did you have time to read the acceptable question guidelines? Specifically: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

For #1, compress the compressed output with gzip. On the other end, decompress twice. (The maximum compression of the gzip format is 1032:1. For highly redundant data, the result of the compression is itself compressible.)

For #2, if you don't have time to write a super simple piece of code to write five bits for each difference (0..30, with 31 being an escape code followed by the next integer with no differencing), then you can't possibly finish your project.

Comment: if you don't have time to read the question, don't answer.  it specifically and plainly says "tightly distributed, though with a tail".  It's literally part of the same sentence.  Therefore, it cannot be coded from 0 to 31.  save your sarcasm, its simply inappropriate and immature.  and it is not a project or homework assignment either, smart guy - you're really batting a thousand on this one.

Comment: If you don't have time to read the answer, then don't ask the question. The answer plainly says "with 31 being an escape code", so you code the differences 0..30 in five bits, but if the difference is greater than 30, you put in a 31, followed by however many bits you need to represent your largest possible integer.

Comment: @cmo By the way, batting a thousand means perfection. So thanks, I guess.