# Algorithm to check if an element is part of a set

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, set

I have a list of elements which I want to hash together to get the root hash (similar to a merkle tree). The requirement is that I need to verify whether an element is present in the root hash. Now the restriction is that, I'll have access only to the root hash and the element which we need to verify at any point of time, so we wont be able to use the merkle tree approach. Have tried bloom filters and similar algorithms but couldn't find a way to handle the false positives. Is there any data structure or algorithm I can follow to get a solution?

Comment: If you just have the hash there is always the possibility of collisions.

Comment: Yes there is. Fully aware of that, just looking for the possibility of a solution for this overlooking the collisions

Comment: How is a merkle tree with just one layer violating your constrains?

Comment: Could you expand on that please? I could have more than 2 elements to in the set.

Comment: Are you allowed to cache values?

Comment: @Surt no I cannot use cache

Comment: You could make a Really Bad Hash(TM) where you set a bit equal to the number you have, then you can see if you already have it already ...

Comment: @Surt I cannot use a bad hash either as they won't account for anagrams

Comment: @bahdotsh: even if a merkle tree is in most cases binary, the definition / idea is not limited to binary trees. You could make a root-node with as many children as your list has elements.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I understand that but to find the proof for validation for any of the leaf node, you need access to a couple of other hashes too(which I won't have access to), hence it isn't a great fit for this scenario

Comment: The question is not very clear. If you have only hashes, you will *always* have a risk of collision.

Comment: I have already answered a similar comment, please go through the discussion properly before saying anything. @Olivier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end your question can be answered with the [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity). Your condensed problem is the maximum compression of your specific set.

To rephrase the  answer: Without any more [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) (see Shannon/Gibbs) on your question you need to let go one or the other: Accurancy or space. If you have a very specific problem, there might be better solutions as entropy is different (e.g. max different elements, size limits, reoccuring patterns, prefixes, ...).

The named algo (Bloomfilter) have been designed to optimize one for the cost of the other side (to say it in easy words: Who cares about a hash collision if the probability is lower than getting struck by lightning or the possibility the CPU itself crashes or earth is hit by asteroid,...). You can precalculate the expected collision probability using a [collision calculator](https://hur.st/bloomfilter/).

So a 64KiB Bloom filter will be able to store up to 20.637 elements before struck by lightning. You can play with the parameters:
https://hur.st/bloomfilter/?n=&p=0.5E-5&m=64KiB&k=

Starting with a hash if you do not like to have any collision is the wrong way. Once information is lost, it will stay lost. You should then look into compressing the set differently. To optimize this operation best, knowledge about the data is needed to help.

If you are not willing (or able) to let go something, you're talking about a set with [lossless compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression). [Shannon's source coding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem)tells you how optimal a lossless compression can theoretical get and how good you are compared to the optimum. If you talk about integers some algos for integer sequence compression are discussed in some papers [here in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14843041/12800717)