# Reversible tuple compression?

Tags: python, hash, tuples, compression

Is there a way to reversibly compress a tuple of integers in Python? I have a large number of 5 digit tuples (values range from 0-100000) that I want to be able to store in a more memory efficient way but I also need to use their original values at a later point.

If I had a tuple like this:

```
test_tuple = (520, 203, 9721, 12, 4839)
```

I'd like to be able to compress it to a single integer value, similar to pythons default `hash` function, except I need to be able to recreate the tuple from the integer value, which is not possible with the `hash` function.

So something like:

```
compressed = compress(test_tuple)
og_tuple = decompress(compressed)
```

Where `compressed` is an integer (or other small memory) representation of `test_tuple` and `og_tuple` is the original tuple extracted from the compressed representation. Ideally the solution should also be fast.

Comment: So are the numbers in the tuple unique? Do you need them in the same order?

Comment: Is there a known maximum size of these tuples? Can we assume they would fit in 4 bytes or 8 bytes?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283299/best-compression-algorithm-for-a-sequence-of-integers?

Comment: @DaniMesejo Numbers are not always unique and the order does need to be maintained.

Comment: @tdelaney all the tuples are 5 integers long

Comment: @NickKeener - I may have misworded that. Is there a known maximum size of the integers in the tuples?

Comment: @tdelaney There is no maximum size but for my application no integer should be above 1 million (slight change from original post where I said 0-100,000s)

Comment: Any meaningful compression will have significant overhead, and won't be effective at small sizes. How many of those tuples are we talking about and in what fashion do you access them? Do you even need to keep them all in memory all the time? This might be an XY problem. | For a naive approach, I'd consider storing the data in a numpy array. Either as unsigned 32bit ints (you waste 20 bits per value, but no overhead at all), or as groups of 3 unsigned 8bit ints, and couple of shifts + ors/adds to recreate the original value (which willl cost some interpreter overhead to reassemble).

Answer (score 2):

This probably isn’t the fastest or smallest form of compressing but it’s prolly the easiest to follow. Get the lengths of all the integers and append that to the integers as a string:

```
test_tuple = (520, 203, 9721, 12, 4839)

strs = list(map(str, test_tuple))
compressed = int(''.join(map(str, map(len, strs))) + ''.join(strs))
```

Output:

```
334245202039721124839
```

Then to decompress, since all tuples contain 5 integers and the lengths won’t be over 9 you know the first 5 characters will be the lengths, so just use that to unpack the integers again. I used `itertools.islice` for this btw:

```
from itertools import islice 

s = str(compressed)
idxs, nums = map(int, s[:5]), [iter(s[5:])]*5
decompressed = tuple(int(''.join(islice(n, i))) for i, n in zip(idxs, nums))
```

Output:

```
(520, 203, 9721, 12, 4839)
```

Comment: thanks! This does work and is simple to implement. I'd still be interested if anyone has ideas for faster and more memory efficient implementations but this should work sufficiently well for my purposes.

Comment: Just say `n = iter(s[5:])` and use that instead of the zipping.

Answer (score 1):

`array` stores fixed length integers efficiently. You could use that to build a single bytes object holding all of your data and then use a compression algorithm like LZMA to slim it down further still.

```
import array
import lzma

test_list = [tuple(range(i, i+5)) for i in range(100_000)]
arr_bytes = b"".join(array.array("I", tup).tobytes() for tup in test_list)
compressed = lzma.compress(arr_bytes)
```

A longer version that includes checking sizes and unwinding back to the original array is

```
import array
import lzma
import sys

# generate a test list and get its size
test_list = [tuple(range(i, i+5)) for i in range(100_000)]
sz = sum(sum(sys.getsizeof(i) for i in tup) for tup in test_list)
sz += sum(sys.getsizeof(tup) for tup in test_list)
sz += sys.getsizeof(test_list)
print("orig size" , sz)

# convert tuples to fixed size array of 4 byte ints, then concat to bytes
arr_format = "I"
arr_item_size = 4
assert array.array("I").itemsize == arr_item_size, "pack to 4 bytes"
arr_len = arr_item_size * 5
arr_bytes = b"".join(array.array(arr_format, tup).tobytes() for tup in test_list)
print("as bytes", len(arr_bytes), f"{len(arr_bytes)/sz*100:.2f}%")

# compress
compressed = lzma.compress(arr_bytes)
print("compressed", len(compressed), f"{len(compressed)/sz*100:.2f}%")

# sanity check that we got the same stuff back
arr_bytes_decompressed = lzma.decompress(compressed)
assert arr_bytes_decompressed == arr_bytes, "decompressed right"

test_list_decompressed = [tuple(array.array(arr_format, arr_bytes_decompressed[i:i+arr_len]))
        for i in range(0, len(arr_bytes_decompressed), arr_len)]
assert test_list_decompressed == test_list, "test list"
```

Running I get

```
orig size 22800980
as bytes 2000000 8.77%
compressed 55972 0.25%
```

The compressed size depends on how random your integers are, but still, that ain't bad!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the obvious solution pops up after going through an answer. Since this is the best solution (IMHO), I'm posting it separately....

Just pickle it.

```
import pickle
import lzma

test_list = [tuple(range(i, i+5)) for i in range(100_000)]
compressed = lzma.compress(pickle.dumps(test_list))
```

More complicated with data measurements...

```
# generate a test list and get its size
test_list = [tuple(range(i, i+5)) for i in range(100_000)]
sz = sum(sum(sys.getsizeof(i) for i in tup) for tup in test_list)
sz += sum(sys.getsizeof(tup) for tup in test_list)
sz += sys.getsizeof(test_list)
print("orig size" , sz)

pickled = pickle.dumps(test_list)
print("pickled", len(pickled), f"{len(pickled)/sz*100:.2f}%")

compressed = lzma.compress(pickled)
print("compressed", len(compressed), f"{len(compressed)/sz*100:.2f}%")
```

Output

```
orig size 22800980
pickled 2143892 9.40%
compressed 152068 0.67%
```

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely super memory efficient but the compression using ```lzma``` step is a bit slow compared to the method provided by @Jab. The decompression is the opposite with this method being much faster but for my application I will be doing many more compressions than decompressions so I need that step to be fast.

Comment: lzma'ing highly repetitive data such as `[tuple(range(i, i+5)) for i in range(100_000)]` doesn't look very meaningful/realistic to me. Try `[tuple(random.choices(range(100_000), k=5)) for i in range(100_000)]` instead.