# Is there a more efficient way of compressing strings of digits when we know something about the structure of the data?

Tags: c#, compression

We have loyalty cards (like credit/debit cards, but processed by our bespoke code, as opposed to ones processed by interfacing with the banks). We need to store transaction data on the cards, as many transactions will be made using offline devices, and only uploaded when the card is next tapped on an online terminal.

Card storage space if limited (typically max 8Kb unless you pay silly prices for very smart cards), so I need to compress the data as much as possible.

Our transaction data is made up of three parts, all of which involve digits only (ie not alphabetic or special characters)...

- Date/time - in the format `yyMMddhhmmssfff`
- Device serial number - 17 digits
- Amount - In pennies, max £999.99, so five digits

Representing this as a string of digits gives 37 digits per transaction.

I tried using the algorithms in `System.IO.Compression` (following the code in [this blog post](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/compress-strings-with-dotnet-and-csharp), and the [accompanying GitHub repo](https://github.com/khalidabuhakmeh/Compressing), not included here as it's bog-standard usage of the classes).

This gave some quite impressive results, with around 72% reduction using the optimal Gzip algorithm.

However, I was wondering if it would be possible to improve on this, given that we know something about the shape of the transaction data. For example, the date/time part of the data breaks down as follows...

- year - not that much restriction here
- month - can only be 1-12
- day - can only be 1-31
- hour - can only be 0-23
- minutes and seconds - can only be 0-59
- milliseconds - no restriction

Anyone any comment of whether or not these restrictions would help help me improve on this compression. Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283299/best-compression-algorithm-for-a-sequence-of-integers

Comment: Why are you using two-digit years? Do you not remember all the Y2K stuff? Or do all your transactions date back to the 20th century? [Long Now](https://longnow.org/ideas/long-now-years-five-digit-dates-and-10k-compliance-at-home)

Comment: Typically you actually require MORE storage when compressing small strings, and I would certainly consider 37 digits to be a small string. Are you actually certain that you gain anything through compression? In my quick tests of both gzip and LZ4, I see a significant increase (~25%) in bytes used, not a reduction

Comment: Not to mention that at 37 bytes per transaction, and assuming you only use half of the storage of the card, you can still store ~110 transactions. Exactly how many transactions are you intending to store offline? It seems like you should establish that first and work backwards to determine your requirements.

Comment: Have you considered using bits to represent parts? i.e month can be encoded in 3 bits, day in 4, year - 1 byte, etc.?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. For example, if you know the earliest Date/time possible, you can use an offset from that. With 15 digits to the 1/1000 of a second, you can cover 31,688 years - assuming you can reduce that range to 1,000 years, you can save two digits, and 100 years three digits, but since you also know all the fields are just 0-9, you can convert the 37 digit number to binary and use 16 bytes.

Comment: You could alternatively map each component into a bit field and also end up with 17 bytes.

Comment: @Chronicle Yes I had seen that one (along with a lot of others here), but that question specifically mentioned that a lot of the integers were in a sequence, and my impression was that this was an important factor in the compression. My case doesn't have that,

Comment: @RobotHead This is a new project, so the earliest transaction date will be whenever we launch. 2 digits for the year gives us nearly 77 years, by which time all of the technology being used here will be way out of date. It's nothing like the Y2K bug, in that we will be in control of all the code, so even if (ha ha) any of it were still around, we would be able to update it well in advance.

Comment: I was being a little facetious!

Comment: @RobotHead Sorry, can't always tell nowadays!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can compress the data into `118` bit (or `15` bytes). So far so good we have ranges:

- Date and Time: `1 Jan 2000 0:0:0.000` up to `1 Jan 2100 0:0:0.000` which is `3_155_760_000_000` milliseconds
- Serial number: `1_000_000_000_000_000_000` possible numbers
- Amount: `1_000_00` in pennies

So we have in total:

```
double dt = (new DateTime(2100, 1, 1) - new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds;
double sn = 1_000_000_000_000_000_000L;
double amount = 1_000_00;

Console.Write(Math.Log2(dt * sn * amount));
```

The result is **117.925470...** bits, `118` bits since we can't use bit partially

**Edit:** Compress and decompress routine:

```
private static byte[] MyCompress(DateTime date, long serial, decimal amount) {
  BigInteger ms = (long)(date - new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds;

  BigInteger value = 
    ms * 1_000_000_000_000_000_000L * 1_000_00 +
    (BigInteger)serial * 1_000_00 +
    (BigInteger)(amount * 100);

  byte[] result = new byte[15];

  for (int i = result.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i, value /= 256) 
    result[i] = (byte)(value % 256);

  return result;
}

private static (DateTime date, long serial, decimal amount) MyDecomress(byte[] data) {
  BigInteger value = data.Aggregate(BigInteger.Zero, (s, a) => s * 256 + a);

  BigInteger amount = value % 1_000_00;
  BigInteger serial = (value / 1_000_00) % 1_000_000_000_000_000_000L;
  BigInteger dt = value / 1_000_00 / 1_000_000_000_000_000_000L;

  return (
    new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds((double)dt),
    (long)serial,
    (decimal)amount / 100M
  );
}
```

Demo:

```
var data = MyCompress(new DateTime(2023, 1, 25, 21, 06, 45), 12345, 345.87m);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", data.Select(b => b.ToString("X2"))));

var back = MyDecomress(data);

Console.Write(back);
```

Output:

```
00 0E 05 4C 23 D7 34 A8 BD E8 F7 CC 3D 95 80 BB
(25.01.2023 21:06:45, 12345, 345.87)
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sHeuWV)

**Edit:** If we can store date and time up to `1/10` second (not up to millsecond) we can use `14` bytes only:

```
private static byte[] MyCompress(DateTime date, long serial, decimal amount) {
  BigInteger ms = (long)(date - new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds / 100;

  BigInteger value = 
    ms * 1_000_000_000_000_000_000L * 1_000_00 +
    (BigInteger)serial * 1_000_00 +
    (BigInteger)(amount * 100);

  byte[] result = new byte[14];

  for (int i = result.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i, value /= 256) 
    result[i] = (byte)(value % 256);

  return result;
}

private static (DateTime date, long serial, decimal amount) MyDecomress(byte[] data) {
  BigInteger value = data.Aggregate(BigInteger.Zero, (s, a) => s * 256 + a);

  BigInteger amount = value % 1_000_00;
  BigInteger serial = (value / 1_000_00) % 1_000_000_000_000_000_000L;
  BigInteger dt = value / 1_000_00 / 1_000_000_000_000_000_000L;

  return (
    new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds((double)dt * 100),
    (long)serial,
    (decimal)amount / 100M
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Still digesting it all, but while playing, I noticed that no matter what values I used for the three parameters, the first byte was always `00` . Are we missing something here, because if it is always zero, it's redundant

Comment: Ah, just read on and seen Kerk's comment. Does that explain the leading zero? If so, please can you update your code to reflect that.

Comment: Actually, it just occurred to me that for our use case, we only need the time to the nearest 1/10th of a second, we don't actually need milliseconds. Would that enable us to reduce the storage even further. I'm still not completely clear on the maths you used to calculate the number of bytes, so please bear with me if this is a dumb question

Comment: (pause for thought) ...and that made me understand why the leading byte is zero! Just read Kerk's answer, and between the two of you I think I now understand. Does that mean I can use your code as-is, and just discard the first byte?

Comment: @Avrohom Yisroel: If date and time must be kept up to `1/10` of second, we can cram the data into `14` bytes (`112` bits)

Answer (score 5):

**Solution #1 (old, 16 bytes):**

You can save two digits (bytes) by using the mentioned restrictions:

1. Combine `month+day` into `dayOfYear` (`000-365`) (for consistency assume there are always 29 days in February);
2. Combine `hours+minutes+seconds` into `timeInSeconds` (`00000-86399`).

Note, that there are may be some other technics you could use to reduce the size of the string.

After this you can convert the number in the string from `base 10` to `base 256`. Thus you get *16 bytes* instead of 37. No mathematical proof, just practical result in the code by link (output at the bottom of the page).
https://ideone.com/SMKb6S

Results:

```
initial: 39 999912312359599999999999999999999999999
base10: 37 9999365863999999999999999999999999999
base256: 16 [7, 133, 206, 204, 233, 237, 90, 213, 156, 154, 224, 34, 63, 255, 255, 255]
base62: 21 EC5zRr0FV71hggqe73b0J
```

And after this you can try some compression methods. However, as noted in comments, it may not work with small amount of data.

**Solution #2 (15 bytes):**

Actually, you can end up with *15 bytes*. <s>[Dmitry Bychenko in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75239640/13557078) used microseconds instead of milliseconds (I don't have enough reputation to point that out in comment).</s> *Fixed.* So, `128 years` will be `4_047_667_200_000 milliseconds` (or something like that).

All the data fits in 15 bytes, and some bits are even left free. You can use them to increase the maximum amount, for example. Here are calculations in Python: https://ideone.com/37Bie3

Results:

```
Target bytes: 15 (120 bits)
Years: 64
  Total bits: 120
  Max amount: £41943.04 (22 bits, 5 free bits used)
Years: 128
  Total bits: 120
  Max amount: £20971.52 (21 bits, 4 free bits used)
Years: 256
  Total bits: 120
  Max amount: £10485.76 (20 bits, 3 free bits used)
Years: 512
  Total bits: 120
  Max amount: £5242.88 (19 bits, 2 free bits used)
Years: 1024
  Total bits: 120
  Max amount: £2621.44 (18 bits, 1 free bits used)
Years: 2048
  Total bits: 120
  Max amount: £1310.72 (17 bits, 0 free bits used)
```

*Edit: perform some formatting to the solution #1, add solution #2.*

Comment: Thank you! My bad, you are absolutely right about microseconds; we can save 1 byte more. Hope you'll quickly get enough reputation to comment, let me start adding +1's ;)

Comment: With answers like this, you'll get rep quickly! Pretty amazing for a new contributor. Vote from me too

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to compress the text version of the data, consider your data and store it in a more efficient format.

A date can be stored in <s>seconds since EPOCH time</s> (EDIT) ticks of a DateTime object which should take 8 bytes (unsigned long).

Your device serial number can be stored in an unsigned long as well, and if there are any leading 0s they can be assumed if its always a fixed 17 digits.

Your amount can be stored in an unsigned int in the range 0 to 99999 and assume the last two digits are after a decimal point.

This gives you a total size of 8 + 8 + 4  = 20 bytes.